# django.db.models.Model could not access property

Tags: python, django, model

First I created a class of Employee, but when I access its property by class name, such as Employee.user_name, it raised an error, I do not know why:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Employee(models.Model):

    employee_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)    
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pwd = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name

the error is below:
>>> Employee.user_name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'user_name'
>>>
```

Comment: What code are you executing and what error are you getting?

Comment: Can you show the code that raises this error? It should be accessed as `employee.user_name` (starting with lowercase)

Comment: the code is:  print(Employee.user_name) and the error is: Employee does not have the attribute of user_name

Answer (score 1):

Your class holds many items within it. You need to tell the model which instance you are wanting by calling it by "pk" or other unique field.

```
user = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
user.user_name
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to get the property of the class, not the instance. I want to access the property of Employee as below: Employee.user_name

Comment: You have to call an instance (object) to access a property. your class "Employee" is full of "objects" that contain properties for each object. Where is the code that shows what you are trying to do with user_name?

Comment: I want to make some templates by the definition of the models.

Comment: There should be some methods to get the property, and I know it should have been overwritten by the metaclass of the models.Model when create the type. The admin template of django could get the defination, so I would have to download the source code of django and do some research.